# Laravel on Windows (w/ Apache) without Docker?

Tags: laravel, windows, apache

I previously used Laravel on a couple of things some years ago, and am thinking of using it again. I usually develop on Windows 10 running Apache (MySQL db), and it would be deployed to Ubuntu.

Looking at the getting started bit of the Larvel docs, it describes a whole load of Docker/WSL2 stuff that I simply do not want to do (it wouldn't be a setup I have further use for, and I'd also have to do it on a couple of different computers I use). Is it possible/easy to ignore this and use the setup I have? I could not find a description of setting up on Windows to use the current version of Laravel apart from with Docker.

Comment: Despite the fact that they are trying to promote using Sail . [installation via composer](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation#installation-via-composer) should still work as normal. However I strongly suggest you make the extra effort of using a docker container especially when your production machine will be  Linux as this will ensure you have a development environment as close to production as possible to catch issues that you would normally not (like e.g. you've accidentally made a file lower case and windows doesn't care)

Comment: That's great, thanks very much (and I really should have seen that)! If it makes a difference to you, by all means add that as an answer and I'll accept it.